# how to implement setselector in listview without changing the caption textcolor of listview items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector

I am having a listview which I am populating using inflater. When I implement selector with some color it actually come on top of listview item which is fine, but it also affecting text of listview.  The textfont color also get changes according to the selector color.
 How can I implement selector without affecting my listview text font color

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: protected Drawable getSelectedItemDrawable(){
  drSelectedItemColor = ColorUtils.getLVSelector(mContext,       Utils.getKeyValue(mapPropertyList, "SelectedItemColor","#44bbbbbb"));
  return drSelectedItemColor;
 }
if(lvContent != null && getSelectedItemDrawable() != null){
     lvContent.setSelector(getSelectedItemDrawable());
}

Comment: I don't think code is needed for this .. I just want to know how we can set selector in android listview without affecting the font color of listview text

Comment: Have you search about it ?

Comment: This is needed because it show your efforts.

Comment: i have searched . but i am not getting appropriate solution for this

Answer (score 0):

layout.xml that includes the ListView:

```
<ListView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector"
   />
```

listitem_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_selected" />
</selector
```

Or, you can set the selector of the View by Overriding the getView() method of your ListAdapter. Check more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

It will help you!!

Comment: what if I want to selector programmatically .?

Answer (score 0):

Android: Programmatically set the listSelector for a ListView to the default for the current theme

```
private static void setDefaultListSelector(ListView listView, Context context) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null, new int[]{android.R.attr.listSelector}, android.R.attr.listViewStyle, 0);
        Drawable drawable = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
        listView.setSelector(drawable);        
    }
```

Comment: thanks garima . but i have tried this. but my probem is the selector is coming as overlay . so the white text of my listview  is coming as pink due to overlay . jus wanted to know anyway u can setseletor as bacground of list view item so text color not get affected

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the position of the current selected item

```
OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                mSelectedItem = position;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

Override the getView method of your adapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            // set your color
        }

        return view;
    }
```